# Add attachments with ActionMailbox TestHelper

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-6, action-mailbox

I want to test attachments with the Action Mailbox [TestHelper](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailbox/TestHelper.html). I see the options for the test helper get passed to the mail object but I can't seem to add attachments. They end up being nil.

This is what I have:

```
receive_inbound_email_from_mail(
      attachments: [
        File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../support/fixtures/image.jpeg'))
      ],
      from: 'from@covfefe.test,
      to: 'acme@example.test'
)
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is [supported in Edge](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailbox/TestHelper.html) but ActionMailbox::TestHelper 6.0.3.2 has not implemented it yet.

As a workaround, I came up with this:

```
subject do
  mail = Mail.new do
    to      'nicolas@test.lindsaar.net.au'
    from    'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net.au>'
    subject 'First multipart email sent with Mail'

    text_part do
      body 'Here is the attachment you wanted'
    end

    html_part do
      content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body '<h1>Funky Title</h1><p>Here is the attachment you wanted</p>'
    end

    add_file File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../support/fixtures/image.jpeg')
  end

  # Tap the route for processing.
  create_inbound_email_from_source(mail.to_s, status: :processing).tap(&:route)
end
```

If you're using edge or a newer version this should work:

```
receive_inbound_email_from_mail do |mail|
  mail.to "David Heinemeier Hansson <david@loudthinking.com>"
  mail.from "Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@bagend.com>"
  mail.subject "Come down to the Shire!"

  mail.text_part do |part|
    part.body "Please join us for a party at Bag End"
  end

  mail.html_part do |part|
    part.body "<h1>Please join us for a party at Bag End</h1>"
  end

  mail.add_file File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../support/fixtures/image.jpeg')
end
```

Note: You'll need to change the file path to suit your needs. And `receive_` methods are the same as `create_` but they process the mail.

Answer (score 0):

A complement to Rimian answer, just in case you want to use 'let' to set up your mail var:

```
let(:mail){
    mail         = Mail.new
    mail.to      = 'to@mail.com'
    mail.from    = 'from@mail.com'
    mail.subject = 'your subject'
    mail.body    = 'test body'
    mail.add_file File.join(fixture_path, 'folder_to_file/file_name.png')
    mail
  }
```

and then

```
subject{
  create_inbound_email_from_source(mail.to_s, status: :processing).tap(&:route)
}
```